# Display inline block

Tags: html, css

I need to create layout like this:

```
     |  two
one  -------
     |  three
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="name">one
    </div>
    <div class="con2">
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.group {
    background-color: #093;
}

div.name {
    background-color:#00F;
    display: inline;
}

div.con2 {
    background-color:#FF6;
    display: inline;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkurY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you consider using a table, as judging by your diagram, thats the semantically correct thing to do?

Comment: Nothing about the diagram suggests that a table expresses the correct semantics. That it has only three cells suggests quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You could use table-cell property (only for ie8+), and provide a fallback solution for ie7-:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkurY/1/

Comment: what would the fall back solution be ?

Comment: float:left + fixed height on both outer divs, and skip the vertical alignment (or use padding-top to mimic vertical alignment)

Comment: sounds good but he had the infamous display inline on his divs so he would be stuck with the same issue as my solution if he wants his content to be inline right?

Comment: dont get me wrong id rather use your solution than a table unless demas was displaying data. but as the designers tells me tables aint for making a page layout they are for displaying data ;p im jsut trying to figure out if we GOT to remove the display inline or if theres a workaround :)

Comment: my guess is that the display:inline was just a first try to achieve the wanted layout, i can't see any other reason why he'd need the divs to be inline...

Comment: good enuf for me ;) +1 for teaching me how float works really ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should float your divs instead.
http://jsfiddle.net/zVjjM/

HTML

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="name">one</div>
    <div class="con2">
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.group {
    background-color: #093;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.name {
    background-color:#00F;
    float: left;
}

div.con2 {
    background-color:#FF6;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.name {
    background-color:#00F;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}

div.con2 {
    background-color:#FF6;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}
```

just add a height  to the one  as tall as the two other zones and then align center the text

Comment: display:inline+float:left is a bit of a strange combination - floating will force the divs to behave as block... / and align center won't work vertically

Comment: sorry thats my bad that would be vertical align ... as for the float making the divs behave as block element i didnt know that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the float for the div.I have updated the code at the foll0wing link
http://jsfiddle.net/mkurY/